# Mi Flora sensor lines crashes Home Assistant

Tags: pi-3, sensor, home-automation

I'm trying to read from my Mi Flora sensors using [this guide](https://home-assistant.io/components/sensor.miflora/). I've found them using hcitool, so I know some things are working. But when I try to put in the lines to run it, the configuration validation checks out but Home Assistant won't start after reboot. I can still log on with ssh, but the front end panel isn't accessible as long as the lines below are in configuration.yaml.

```
sensor:
  - platform: miflora
    mac: "C4:7C:8D:62:0B:B0"
    monitored_conditions:
      - temperature
```

What is going wrong? Is there a step I'm missing? I've noticed I haven't really installed any mi flora packages specifically, but there doesn't seem to be any resources on how to do that, so I'm assuming it's already built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by accident! I had these lines further up in configuration.yaml.

```
sensor:
   platform: yr
```

Turns out Home Assistant can't reuse the line "sensor:". You need to put all things underneath the same line.

When I added the mi flora lines under the existing "sensor:" (and added a "–" to platform: yr as below) it worked.

```
sensor:
  - platform: yr
  - platform: miflora
    mac: "C4:7C:8D:62:0B:B0"
    monitored_conditions:
      - temperature
```

Hope this helps someone else!